# Weird result for a do loop with FORTRAN+OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, race-condition

First I compiled the code without `-fopenmp`, and run the code, got a serial result which is a benchmark.
Second I considered use OpenMP to speed up my code.

There are two weird results:
1.The result obtained by

```
   !$OMP CRITICAL
       p1=p1+1
   !$OMP END CRITICAL
```

is a little difference (1%) with serial result. My code does not contain random number so it must be wrong.
2. If I replace `!$OMP CRITICAL` with `!$OMP ATOMIC` and delete `!$OMP END CRITICAL`, the results between these two, are totally different. Aren't the two can be replaced by each other at this situation for `p1=p1+1` ?

My thoughts:
1. The most common problems could be using a thread-not-safe subroutine. But I can not find one in the code below.

Here is a fraction copied from my code.

ATTENTION:

1. Variables other than i,j,k,k1,k2,k3,distance are considered "SHARED"
2. The code is below is the ONLY part I parallelized in the whole code.
3. (i,j,k,k1,k2,k3, distance) are not used after the parallel loop, so the uncertainty of private variables declared by "PRIVATE" will not be considered.

   ```
   p1=0;

   !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(i,j,k,k1,k2,k3,distance)
   !$OMP DO
   do i=1,N_MESH;do j=1,N_MESH;do k=1,N_MESH;

      !$OMP CRITICAL
      p1=p1+1
      !$OMP END CRITICAL

      ! - box-1. special treatment for doing specturm operations for FFT.
      if (i.lt.(N_MESH/2+1))then
          k1=i-1
      elseif (i.eq.N_MESH/2+1) then
          k1=0
      else
          k1=i-1-N_MESH
      endif

      if (j.lt.(N_MESH/2+1))then
          k2=j-1
      elseif (j.eq.N_MESH/2+1)then
          k2=0
      else
          k2=j-1-N_MESH
      endif

      if (k.lt.(N_MESH/2+1))then
          k3=k-1
      elseif (k.eq.N_MESH/2+1)then
          k3=0
      else
          k3=k-1-N_MESH
      endif

      ! =============distance =====================
      distance=(k1*k1)+(k2*k2)+(k3*k3);

      ! -----============put them into =======================
      final_index(p1,l) = nint(dsqrt(distance));

      if (((k1.eq.0).AND.(k2.eq.0)).AND.(k3.eq.0)) THEN
         final(p1,l)=0d0
      else
         final(p1,l)=(abs(fu(i,j,k))**2+abs(fv(i,j,k))**2+abs(fw(i,j,k))**2)/2d0

      endif

   enddo;enddo;enddo
   !$OMP END DO
   !$OMP END PARALLEL
   ```

Comment: I'm in a bit of a hurry so this may be wrong. I don't see any guarantee that this statement -- `final_index(p1,l) = nint(dsqrt(distance))` -- won't be executed by multiple threads with the same *lhs*. `final_index`, `p1`, and `l` all seem to be shared.  Indeed, I'm struggling to find where `l` gets any value at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `p1` is shared, and may change during the main body of the loop.

Let's say that you have two threads and p1 starts at zero, and that they start at the same time. First rank 0 reaches the critical section and increments `p1` to 1 while rank 1 is waiting for the critical section to end. Once rank 0 is done incrementing `p1`, it starts executing the rest of the code, but at the same time rank 1 starts executing the critical section, and increments `p1`. It is not guaranteed that rank 0 will reach the `final(p1,l) = ...` statements before `p1` has become 2. If this happens, `final(1,l)` will never be updated. So there is a race condition.

To avoid this problem, I recommend that you manually compute `p1` based on `i`, `j` and `k`. That will let you make `p1` private, save you a critical section, and remove this race condition.

```
p1 = k + N_MESH*(j-1+N_MESH*(i-1))
```

Comment: Great answer! I really didn't think about that could happen! I work until 4am. So in conclusion, race condition can happen not only in multiple threads writing/reading at the same time (like a=a+1) but also more than one place read/writing, like, in two distant places, in the range of parallel region. Because during executing line by line, the shared variable can be changed. The solution, like you said, is usually looking for a relationship between private variables and that shared variables.

Comment: @PabPeter yes, each thread can be anywhere in the parallel section -- they do not all execute the same line of code at the same times.  You have to consider all places a shared variable can be written to / read from in determining thread safety.